# multiple URL rewrites in same .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I currently have a site that contains individual pages for a companies stores as well as standard pages such as about, contact etc.

I have a simple URL rewrite rule in the htaccess file so that these urls are written as

`https://sitename.com/manchester` or `https://sitename.com/about` instead of `https://sitename.com/manchester.php` and `https://sitename.com/about.php` etc

As its growing I'm now moving to a database structure for the stores, so instead of creating individual pages for each store I'm serving them up in a query with a `select_store.php` file ie `https://sitename.com/select_store.php?store=manchester` etc

I want to continue however rewriting the urls as before so still just `/manchester` etc but how does this work when I have some URLs that should redirect to select_store.php and others that should simply add .php onto the end of the url?

What's the best way to do this? Do I write individual rewrites for the standard pages? about, contact etc? and then a catch all for anything else to go the `select_store.php`?

Or do I redirect everything to select_store and then redirect the likes of about, contact in there? (doesn't sound very SEO friendly though).

My current .htaccess is:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

edited to add additional examples.

currently all pages are suffixed with .php so we have the following:
https://sitename.com/manchester redirects to https://sitename.com/manchester.php
https://sitename.com/liverpool redirects to https://sitename.com/liverpool.php
https://sitename.com/about redirects to https://sitename.com/about.php

I want the stores (in above example manchester & liverpool, but in reality theres a dozen and more adding regularly) to redirect to the likes of:
https://sitename.com/select_shop.php?shop=manchester

while the standard pages (about, contact, menu etc) to continue to redirect as:
https://sitename.com/about.php

```
https://sitename.com/contact.php
```

Comment: Could you please do share your .htaccess file in your question with CODE TAGS. Also if you could mention URLs(in CODE TAGS) from which all url to which all url you want to redirect/rewrite for better understanding of your question, thank you.

Comment: question updated to include the current htaccess

Comment: Thank you for adding your htaccess file, For `I have some URLs that should redirect to select_store.php and others that should simply add .php onto the end of the url`, could you please do add few samples/example URLs so that we could understand question better.

Comment: updated as above.

Answer (score 0):

So the answer to this turned out to be far simpler than I assumed.

You have a single line for each of the "standard" pages index, about, menu etc, for example

```
RewriteRule ^about$ about.php [NC,L]
```

telling them to redirect to the .php file and then have the code to pass anything else to the select_shop page

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ select_shop.php?shop=$1 [NC,L]
```

so the complete file would be something like:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^about$ about.php [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^menu$ menu.php [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^franchise$ franchise.php [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^meet-the-team$ meet-the-team.php [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^events$ events.php [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^find-contact-us$ find-contact-us.php [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^join-our-team.php$ join-our-team.php [NC,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ select_shop.php?shop=$1 [NC,L]

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```